# autofiltering and autocopying filtered result in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am working between 2 sheets.
Sheet 1 at E10 will have a 4 diget Post Code entered.
Sheet 2 has in column A Post Codes (all 4 numeric diget) between A19:A2949.   Next to these post codes is a Zone Code (all alpha) and therefore covering B19:B2949.
A filter using "Equals" the post code (at E10 Sheet 1) filters down to the Zone Code required.
The Zone Code is then entered into H6 on Sheet 2 to establish specific freight rates.

Is it possible to have the entire process automated so that I only need to enter the post code into E10 on Sheet 1?   Thank you for any help in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is.

Use following formula in H6 on Sheet 2:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!E10,A19:B2949,2)
```

Zone code will be populated into E6 on sheet 2 when you enter post code in E10 on sheet 1.

P.S. I am assuming the name of Sheet 1 as `Sheet1`. If it is something different, just modify the name in formula.

Comment: Thank you so much - works so well and is so much easier than the way I was trying to do it!